# How to merge two json objects (one is array inside of another)

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, formbuilder

I'm having problem joining those two

```
let tasks = [];

    this.tasks.map(it => {
        tasks.push(
            {
                'prop1': it['prop1'],
                'prop2': it['prop2'],
                'prop3': it['prop3'],
            }
        );
    });

    let projects = {
        'title': this.projectForm.value['title'],
        'state': this.projectForm.value['state'],
        'comment': this.projectForm.value['comment'],
        'other': 
        // here I want to have the whole "tasks" array with "prop1", "prop2", "prop3".
    };
```

How to throw the whole response from tasks to projects->other? 
I have good response when I console.log tasks, but projects just don't have "other" prop and that makes my form invalid.

Forms are made with Angular FormBuilder.

(Just letting you know that in this case using ":" doesn't work - array is not assigned and property "other" is completely skipped in console etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use spread Operator**

*This will do the thing you need*

```
let otherObject= {...tasks};

let projects= {'other': {...otherObject}, 'title': this.projectForm.value['title'],
        'state': this.projectForm.value['state'],
        'comment': this.projectForm.value['comment']
    }
```

**Note spread operator starts with '...' and is ES6 feature**

I am adding further an example from using browser console ( chrome), This should help to clarify it further.

[image]

So one mate raised a point in the comments about having an array in spread in place of single object
Below is something you can refer ;) enjoy!!

[image]

Adding one more way of doing it using spread operator :

[image]

Comment: personAddressVar = {street: ""rue de", city: "Brussels"}
now
doing {...personAddressVar} will just create a shallow copy of the same object it good to have, but what's the need of creating two copies one in otherObject then copy of otherObject in 'other': 'value'

and also in the question tasks seem to be an array of objects but not an object.

Comment: No need of creating otherObject thats why gave an example by running in console

Comment: but not like {...'an array'}
'tasks' is an array but not an object so {...tasks} will create key-value pairs having keys as numbers 0,1,2...

Comment: Asked question and pasted answer no where matches the uploaded images.
I just want to understand if I am going somewhere wrong.

Comment: I have already added sample array spread to ans. Can you try and post once if it is not working  ?

Comment: This is the verified solution for the question, please let me know how it's correct?
https://repl.it/repls/ClearcutBossyJavadocs

Comment: I do not understand your problem specifically. What you are trying to solve. May be you are understating it completely wrong. Every thing is treated as an Object in Javascript since you are a MEAN stack so this concept is always known.
Now, Array does not mean it always has to be of primitives like [1,2,3,4 ], it can be aray of object of key value as well

Comment: @Ariz What Sanyam wrote works in my example. You are not able to see it in repl because I use values from formBuilder etc. (what I wrote in my post is not my whole code, just a part I have problem with)

Comment: @Ariz. look at the screenshots. Spread does the job. You have person with name and last name and adress which is array/object (Sanyam considered your point with arrays and added info about it). Adress inside has street and city and thanks to spread you simply put those values inside the form you want. You can't see that because you are not getting any input, don't have database with info you could return. [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) - try to make simple form, get data and THEN use this answer and look for result in console :)

Comment: @Aerogirl screenshots are perfectly fine, I do understand javascript.
What I did not understand is putting an array inside an object with spread like {...array} where {...arrayOfObjects[i]} is understandable.
could be related to angular forms (I don't have much knowledge of UI).

Comment: @Ariz may be you are looking for this ?

let tasks = [{
                'prop1': 'prop1',
                'prop2': 'prop2',
                'prop3': 'prop3',
            },
            {
                'prop4': 'prop1',
                'prop2': 'prop2',
                'prop6': 'prop3',
            }]


let otherObject= [...tasks];

let projects= {'other': [...otherObject], 'title':'title',
        'state': 'state',
        'comment': 'comment'
    }


    console.log(projects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple equal `:` to concat two objects is typescript, and also here is online environment you can see join two objects, (your example) :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdjv2k